# What is the threshold for ALL_ROWS flag of DBMS_CHANGE_NOTIFICATION?

Tags: database, oracle, plsql

I am trying to create a cache for a table in Oracle DB. I monitor the changes in the DB using DBMS_CHANGE_NOTIFICATION to automatically update the cache.

This is however only working in a satisfactory manner as long as the updates I do are rather small -- if I delete large portion of rows, the ALL_ROWS flag of the notification structure is set to *true* and the array of ROWIDs is *NULL*.

By trial and error I found out that the threshold for number of updated rows is about 100 rows which is really too little. If a table contains several million rows and I delete a thousand I do not get information on what was updated and I have to refresh the cache for the whole table which is unacceptable.

Can I somehow change this threshold? I could not find a specific answer in documentation:

> If the ALL_ROWS (0x1) bit is set it means that either the entire table
>   is modified (for example, DELETE * FROM t) or row level granularity of
>   information is not requested or not available in the notification and
>   the receiver has to conservatively assume that the entire table has
>   been invalidated.

This only gives me vague information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is a procedure where you can specify the value:

[SET_ROWID_THRESHOLD](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_cqnotif.htm#ARPLS73495)

It would be nice if I could look up what the current value is with a getter, I haven't found it.

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_chngnt.htm#CIHDAGEC) I found this:

> If the ALL_ROWS bit is set in the table operation flag, then it means
>   that all rows within the table may have been potentially modified. In
>   addition to operations like TRUNCATE that affect all rows in the
>   tables, this bit may also be set if individual rowids have been rolled
>   up into a FULL table invalidation.
>
> This can occur if too many rows were modified on a given table in a
>   single transaction (more than 80) or the total shared memory
>   consumption due to rowids on the RDBMS is determined too large
>   (exceeds 1 % of the dynamic shared pool size). In this case, the
>   recipient must conservatively assume that the entire table has been
>   invalidated and the callback/application must be able to handle this
>   condition.

I rolled by own solution years ago, which gives me control/flexibility, but perhaps someone has a workaround for you (commit in small chunks of 50? but what if your app isn't the only one changing the table?).  I think the whole point is to only cache tables that are slowly changing, but this restriction does seem silly to me.

Comment: Your answer suggests a possible solution would be increasing the size of the shared pool. Not sure that it's a fantastic solution as you're essentially committing to use RAM for this - if it store everything in RAM then fine it's something you have to do. If it doesn't then it's just a waste...

Comment: @tbone: "I rolled by own solution years ago" -- what was the solution?

Comment: @Blaf its an entire package thats specific to my environment and business needs, not really something I'd post here.  But there are many caching options available today that don't rely on pushing changes from the db side.  [Ehcache](http://ehcache.org/) is one open-source option you may look into.